# 3.6.2 PDE Headless (feature) build doesn't recognize included features

Tags: eclipse, build, rcp, pde

I use topLevelElementType = feature and topLevelElementId = my.main.feature as properties. 'my.main.feature' contains two included features and one plugin. 3.6.2 PDE plugin generates feature build.xml with empty "all.features" target. Plugin recognized fine for both.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just missed 'build.properties' files in folders of features. 
So, if you get "@dot folder not found" error, problem with jar compilation or problem with build.xml generation and your feature are not binary - check that 'build.properties' exists.